# how to change size of thumb of scroll bar - JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, scrollbar

Is it possible to change the thumb/handle size of the scroll bar? I checked all over the internet, it says that I need to create my own custom scroll bar. There is no way to change the size of the thumb of the scroll bar. Suggestions guys!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Webkit, you can adjust the scrollbar size with CSS.

See chris Coyier's article http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Elements

```
::-webkit-scrollbar              { /* 1 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-button       { /* 2 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track        { /* 3 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  { /* 4 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb        { /* 5 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner       { /* 6 */ }
::-webkit-resizer                { /* 7 */ }
```

Edit: If you need to support all browsers, Then you have to implement jquery plugin, as the scroll bar is not rendering by Browser but the Operating system.

Comment: Need to support all browsers.. :(

Comment: Then you have to implement jquery plugin, as the scroll bar is not rendering by Browser but the Operating system.